# I need to copy a file from server A that I can only access by first connecting to server B

Tags: macos, terminal, scp

I need to copy a file (~9 gigs) from a server, let's call it server B. I can only ssh into server B by first connecting to server A. I am trying to use scp to copy a file to my local machine. I was simply going to use scp to copy the file first to server A, and then again to copy to my local machine - unfortunately though there is only like half a gig of disk space available to me on server A. Is there any way to copy it directly from server B? I cannot use ssh to connect to server B directly from my computer. I'm using terminal on mac.

Comment: Sounds like you can't. Server A is acting like a Jump Box to the other server, and based on what you are telling us here, there is no other connection alternative.

Comment: Ah bummer. Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computer and the jump host (server A) are both running OpenSSH v7.3 or later, you can use the ProxyJump option to do this automatically:

```
scp -oProxyJump=userA@serverA userB@serverB:remoteFile localDest
```

What this does is open an SSH connection to server A, then tunnel over that to open an SSH (/scp) connection from the local computer to server B, then transfer the file over that connection. Note that it'll ask for two passwords as it connects: first serverA, then serverB.

You can also automate this by creating an ssh config file on your computer (~/.ssh/config), and making an entry something like this:

```
Host serverB
    ProxyJump userA@serverA
```

...which tells ssh (and scp) to automatically do the ProxyJump whenever you request a connection to serverB. See the [OpenSSH docs on the config file](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) for more details.

If you don't have a new enough OpenSSH on both computers but `netcat` (or `nc` or something similar) is available on serverA, you can probably also get the same effect with a ProxyCommand option. See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1218078/my-scp-doesnt-have-proxyjump-option).

Comment: Thank you Gordon this was exactly what I was looking for!